# How to obtain correct windows phone version in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-phone-8.1, windows-10-universal

In the recent version Xamarin.Forms the Device.OS property returns for both Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 UWP the "Windows" value.
Is there a way to obtain a correct Device OS version to distinguish between the Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 10 UWP?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Device.Idiom == TargetIdiom.Desktop)
{ 
    // UWP
}
else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
{ 
    // WinPhone
}
else if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.Windows)
{ 
    // Windows 8
}
```

Just to explain, Windows 8 Idiom is TargetIdiom.Tablet, so the only OS that returns true to TargetIdiom.Desktop is UWP.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I need to distinguish between the Windows UWP mobile and Windows Phone 8.1. The xamarin returns Device.OS "Windows" for the both.

Comment: And Device.Idiom?

Comment: My project is not intended to be used on any kind of devices other than mobile phones. So on these devices Device.Idiom is always "Phone" and the Device.OS is "Windows".

Comment: Oh sure, so, if you didn't tried this yet, try to use Device.RuntimePlatform. It'll return a string that you can compare with Device.Windows or Device.WinPhone. I think this will suit your needs :)